# Single Processor Systems Vs Multi Processor Systems

Tags: process, operating-system, multicore

I'm working with operating systems. so i'm interested in single processor systems and multi multiprocessor systems. So i want to know about the differences between single processor systems and multi processor systems.

Comment: Your question is by far too broad. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A single processor system contains only one processor. So only one process can be executed at a time and then the process is selected from the ready queue. Even if there are multiple applications need to be executed, since the system contains a single processor and only one process can be executed at a time.

But multi processors contains two or more processors so multiple applications can be executed simultaneously. There can be two main types of symmetric or asymmetric multiprocessing which helps many processors can perform different tasks.

Answer (score -2):

A Single processor contains only one processor. A single processor performs the only process at a given time and it carries out the next process in the queue after the completion of the current process.